# how to pass --no-buffer option in pycurl

Tags: libcurl, pycurl

I want to disable the buffering of the output stream. curl  has the option --no-buffer to disable that buffering.
I am searching for this option in pyCurl but did not find any in documentation. Could you please guide me here?

Answer (score 0):

`--no-buffer` is for the tool only and is not an option passed to libcurl - it probably has no counter-part in pycurl.

The curl tool implements this option by calling fflush() on the output stream at the end of the write callback. You can most likely implement the same thing in your pycurl-using application.